# Использование удалённой функции SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Я начинаю путешествие по просторам C++, и решил зайти с сложного, попутно разбирая проблемы.

Если это важно, использую Windows 11 и компилятор MinGW и такой же генератор для CMake.

Скачал я шаблон с официальной страницы гитхаба:

https://github.com/SFML/cmake-sfml-project/

а когда пытаюсь его скомпилировать (через CMake и Make), выдаёт ошибку на стадии создания самого исполнительного файла (после команды `make`)

```
use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const sf::RenderWindow&)'
```

на строке `auto window = sf::RenderWindow{{1920u, 1080u}, "CMake SFML Project"};`

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
  auto window = sf::RenderWindow{{1920u, 1080u}, "CMake SFML Project"};
  window.setFramerateLimit(144);

  while (window.isOpen()) {
    for (auto event = sf::Event{}; window.pollEvent(event);) {
      if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
        window.close();
      }
    }

    window.clear();
    window.display();
  }
}
```

В файлах я ничего не менял, кроме изменения генератора для CMake. Гуглёж проблемы не помог, ибо такое появляется только в чужом коде в котором поди пойми что и что значит, а вот с официальным шаблоном такого ни у кого не было. Прошу помочь разобраться с данным недоразумением.

Лог консоли: https://pastebin.com/kG1wnHSb

Comment: Этот код должен работать в C++17 и новее (попробуйте `-std=c++17`). Но раз этот режим не стоит по дефолту, значит сам MinGW старый. Новый нормальный можно поставить из [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2).

Comment: пишите короче: `sf::RenderWindow window{{1920u, 1080u}, "CMake SFML Project"};` Конструкция `auto ... =` не имеет смысла, когда тип все равно явно указан справа.

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь с ником "**HolyBlackCat**" в действительности был прав, и во всё виновата версия MinGW компилятора, которую я ставил с официального сайта и которая ограничивалась версией 6.3.

Решение: установка MinGW-w64 через MSYS2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2

Comment: А что это за официальный сайт такой был?